# what is the fairest ratio of k to n for this game

Tags: game-theory

Here is a description of a two player game with players plr1 and plr2 that is played on a n by n grid.

Players take turns filling cells in the grid. plr1 goes first and wins by completing a straight (not diagonal) line of n filled cells on the grid. plr2 wins if plr1 has not won before k cells have been filled.

Just to be clear, plr1 must complete the line n filled cells, that is to say, if plr2 were to complete such a line this would not result in a win for plr1. Additionally this line must be exactly of length n. It cannot exceed n for it to be a win.

Obviously, n < k < n<sup>2</sup>

The question is to find what the "fairest" ratio of k to n is for this type of game. By fair I mean a game that would been won approximately equally often by plr1 and plr2 assuming they were of relatively similar skill. Of course, this ratio may vary as n increases, so the question might also be stated as finding the fairest k for a given n.

Thanks

Comment: reminds me somehow of tictactoe, which can't be won when played by imaginary nash players? or is there something i am missing? Or otherwise said: this is no game of chance, thus their is no fair game

Comment: a trick that comes from another poster in a related topic: just flip a coin before each round to determine the starting player. problem solved, let k and n be whatever you want ;)

Comment: A more interesting question: playing on an infinite grid, and a target length $n$, does there exist a $k$ for which player $1$ has a winning strategy?  Or will player $2$ always win regardless the value of $k$ (*with perfect play by both players*)

Comment: @JMoravitz well n has to be at least >3, otherwise its trivial, also i'd say k has to be at least 2n

Comment: I have avoided the infinite board because it means the game cannot be won by plr2 and the idea was to create a (close to) fair game. Also, as pointed out, the game is unfair. I realize this and am simply looking for the "fairest" ratio of k to n

Comment: never mind what I said about the infinite board, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Fred sorry, just understood that. Re the infinite game though, plr 1 can then finish a line by extending it, so $k=2n+1$ suffices there.

Comment: sorry i was unclear, the line that plr1 creates must be exactly of length n. if the resulting line is longer it is not a win for plr1

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. Wanted to make this a comment, but don't have the reputation for it. A few questions, observations:

- on a $2 \times 2$ grid, it would seem that plr1 wins always. yes?
- on a $3 \times 3$ grid, it would seem that plr2 can always prevent plr1 from winning
- on a $4 \times 4$ grid, I can't find a way for plr1 to win either as it seems that plr2 can usually get a "rook covering" of the board [putting rooks on a chessboard so that no rook is attacking another rook, but the entire board is under rook surveillance] or a weaker form of it [the rooks can attack each other].

can plr1 ever win for any $k$ for $n > 2$? or maybe I understood the question incorrectly? Are the players alternating turns or do they take turns like plr1, plr2, plr2, plr1, plr1, plr2, plr2, plr1, plr1, etc.?

Comment: they alternate plr1 plr2 plr1 plr2 ect

Comment: I disagree on your second point. let the grid be numbered from left to right top to bottom 1-9 and consider these moves: 5,1,2, 3 or 8, 8 or 3. this is a win for plr1

Comment: For $n=3$, unless I misunderstand, plr1 wins in at most 5 moves (i.e. by his third move).  If plr2 plays in the same row or column as plr1, plr1 finishes that row or column.  Otherwise plr1's second move is in the intersection of the row of his first move and the column of plr2's first move,  plr1's third move will complete either that row or that column.

Comment: ah, so it depends of how you set k, if k>5 plr1 wins. The question is what is the "fairest" k to n ratio, so you might suggest in this case a ratio of 2/3

Comment: if k>(n-1)^2 then plr1 will always win becuase regardless of where they play a line will be completed

Comment: @RobertIsrael clearly I've misunderstood. for the $n=3$ case isn't it tic-tac-toe but easier for plr2 to force a tic-tac-toe draw since the diagonals are out of the question?

Comment: What are you assuming k to be in this case?

Comment: @Math Misery: it's not tic tac toe, because plr 1 can use squares filled by plr 2

Comment: @fred, @ shagnik, where in the rules is it implied that squares can be shared or overwritten?  If squares shared, can't player 1 completely ignore player 2 and win in n turns?  If overwritten, can't player 2 continually overwrite player 1's moves?

Comment: There are only two kinds of squares (I called them cells in the question), filled and unfilled. Players take turns filling a single cell. plr1 can't ignore plr2 because plr2 may complete a line stopping plr1 from completing it. to win plr1 must be the one to complete the line and the line must be exactly of length n.